# background-size:cover; alternative for IE6+

Tags: internet-explorer, css, background-image

I need a quick fix for `body{background-size:cover;}` to work in IE6+.  What is the best way to go about it? JavaScript/jQuery, or some sketchy CSS2 tricks, meaning I will have to put the image in a page element instead of just in the CSS.

Comment: IE6? Seriously? Have you looked at their analytics to make sure it is worth the effort? I have seen CSS3 hacks for IE6 for border-radius, box-shadow, and linear-gradient, but not for any of the background properties. I do have an answer for you that should work though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you must do it, it would seem the easiest way would be to use an absolutely positioned image with a height and width of 100%. Then use z-index to get the rest of the content on top of the image.

Comment: LOL yeah really. I dropped support late last year, I don't even do it if the client asks anymore. It's time to let it die!!

Answer (score 2):

You can use IEFilters.  See [this article](http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_Scale_Background_image_to_browser_size-17590.html).